# Question about "commutation" relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm reading Dummit & Foote, *Abstract Algebra* and they briefly mention something about a ' "commutation" relation', such as $xy = yx^2$. In general, if we have the relation $xy = y^i x^j$, where $x,y$ generate the (finite) group $G$, it seems to me that any element of the group can be written in the form $y^m x^n$ for some (nonnegative integers) $m,n$. This is because any group element is just some string of $x$'s and $y$'s, and we can use the commutation relation to "move each $y$ to the left".

My question is: What about moving the $y$'s to the right? I.e. when can we write any group element as $x^m y^n$ for some $m,n$? Obviously we could do this if we have a "commutation" relation $yx = x^sy^t$, but what about if we only have the "commutation" relation $xy = y^i x^j$? Are there certain additional properties/relations of the group (aside from being abelian) that will guarantee the ability to write any element of the group both as a string of $y$'s then $x$'s as well as a string of $x$'s then $y$'s?

I'm asking this question because it seems fairly natural: if a group is generated by two elements and it has a "commutation" relation, then any "action"/"move" can be done by first performing the first move $x$ repeatedly, and then performing the second move $y$ repeatedly. Then naturally we might ask if we can also do it the other way around: first repeat the move $y$, then repeat the move $x$.

Edit: As an example, the dihedral group for a regular $n$-gon has the relation $rs = sr^{-1}$ (or $rs = sr^{n-1}$ if we require nonnegative powers). By multiplying both sides on the left by $s$ and on the right by $s$ as well, we get $sr = r^{-1}s$ (since $s^2 = 1$). So we have both "commutation" relations for $rs$ and $sr$. This tells us that any symmetry can be obtained either by rotations then reflections or by reflections then rotations.

Comment: What you write in the first paragraph is not true in general. The relation $xy=yx^2$ does not allow you to write every element as $y^mx^n$. It is not true that every element can be written in that form in the group defined by that relation, the Baumslag-Solitar group ${\rm BS}(1,2) = \langle x,y \mid xy=yx^2 \rangle$.

Comment: If you can write every element of your group $\langle x, y\rangle$ as $x^iy^j$ then it either contains an element of finite order, or is infinite cyclic, or is a "Zappa-Szep product" $\mathbb{Z\bowtie Z}$. Such products generalise semidirect products, as the "internal" definition is that $G=HK$ with $H\cap K=1$ (no assumptions on normality). There had been some work on presentations of such groups, and indeed I think all such groups (but not necessarily all presentations which define them) have been classified.

Comment: Having a look at https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102977886 seems useful

Comment: @DerekHolt But if we have a string of $x$'s and $y$'s, e.g. the string $xxyxxxyx$, couldn't we group each $xy$ and exchange it with $yx^2$, and do this for each $y$ until they are all on the left? I am assuming $G$ is a finite group, and that $G$ is generated by $x,y$ (in the sense that every element of $G$ can be written as a finite product of $x$'s and $y$'s). For reference, this is my understanding of what's written on the top of p.26 of Dummit & Foote.

Comment: The problem is that you have no way of rewriting $x^{-1}y$.

Comment: @Derek Ok in general that could be true, but for a finite group that is generated by some generators, couldn't every element (including $x^{-1}$) be written as a product of nonnegative powers of those generators?

Comment: @twosigma The finite groups which may be written like this, and where additionally $\langle x\rangle\cap\langle y\rangle=1$ (as in my above comment), were classified by Jesse Douglas (the first fields medalist) in a series of papers: On finite groups with two independent generators I-IV, Proc. Nat, Acad. Sci. USA 37, 1951.

Comment: @twosigma Yes you are right. If the group $G$ is finite - or even if the element $x$ has finite order - then $x^{-1}$ can be written as $x^k$ for some $k > 0$, and then you can indeed write every element of $G$ in the from $x^iy^j$. And in that case Thomas Andrew's argument works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $g\in G$ write $g^{-1}=x^iy^j,$ with $0\leq i<o(x), 0\leq j<o(y).$ Then $$g=y^{-j}x^{-i}=y^{o(y)-j}x^{o(x)-i}$$

Comment: Your formulas are correct (i the order of the elements is finite) but the premiss of the OP is already wrong: "any element of the group can be written in the form $y^mx^n$ for some (nonnegative integers) m,n" so this answer isn't useful.